# Jenkins Integration with Jira issue

Tags: jenkins, jira

I have installed Jenkins Plugin for JIRA on my JIRA installation and also JIRA Plugin for Jenkins on to my Jenkins installation. I have added an application link in JIRA settings.

I am facing below issue:

1) On Application Links page there is a warning that my Jenkins Application "seems to be offline". While Adding a jenkins link it gives me error : The host doesn't respond. Change the url or click next to confirm.

Jira Version - 6.0.5

Jenkins Version - 1.562

Jenkins-Jira Plugin Version - 1.4.3

Thanks to anybody who's willing to help me out on this.

Comment: what are the urls you are using to link the two?

Answer (score 11):

You can follow four steps:

1. **Install JIRA Plugin in Jenkins**

In Jenkins:

```
Manage Jenkins > manager plugins > available
```

search and choose Jenkins JIRA plugin , Jenkins `JiraTestResultReporter` plugin and Jenkins JIRA Issue Updater

2. **Install Jenkins Plugin in JIRA.**

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.marvelution.jira.plugins.jenkins
see: Installation section.

3. **Add Jenkins 's Application Links in JIRA**

The integration between JIRA and Jenkins has Application Links as its base. This allows administrators to configure and manage the Jenkins

To get started, go to `[JIRA_BASEURL]/plugins/servlet/applinks/listApplicationLinks` and click on the Add Application Link button to add a new Application Link for Jenkins.
  or `administration > plugin > Application Link > add Application Link;` do as instruction

**note:** Optionally, but required if Jenkins is secured,

configure Outgoing Authentication that JIRA should use.

To do this, click on the Edit link next to the Jenkins Application Link, and select OutGoing Authentication tab

Provide the `Username` of the user to use to authenticate against Jenkins with

Provide the Password of the use

4. **Jenkins Configuration**

After the installation of the Jenkins Plugin for JIRA, and the configuration of at-least one Application Link, administrators will be able to control which Jobs are included in the synchronisation process and which aren't.

in **Administration > plugins (add-ons) >Jenkins Configuration**

Download JIRA plugin for Jenkins and install this plugin in Jenkins

**way 1:** copy it to Jenkins's plugin folder. and restart Jenkins

**way2:** Manage Jenkins > manager plugins > advanced > Upload Plugin . Choose file and upload then restart Jenkins

**Enable Jenkins job in JIRA** 
then just use a known JIRA Issue Key in a commit message of your source code repo

Jenkins will make all the change sets (commits) available to the JIRA plugin when syncing a build.

The sync process uses the change sets to look for JIRA Issue Keys. Once this process locates a link, then that build will be available in the CI Build Panels.

download jenkins-jira-plugin at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.marvelution.jira.plugins/jenkins-jira-plugin